# CSS remove duplicate code in both classes?

Tags: css

I have below css style applied my html anchor tag.

```
.my_button .left {
        float: left;
        width: 10px;
        height: 19px;
        background: url("./images/bl.png") left center no-repeat;
    }

    .my_button .right {
        float: left;
        width: 10px;
        height: 19px;
        background: url("./images/br.png") left center no-repeat;
    }
```

On mouse over on anchor tag am applying one more css style. Below code is almost similar to above CSS style excpet background url. is it possible to avoid duplicate css code?

```
.my_button_hover .left {
        float: left;
        width: 10px;
        height: 19px;
        background: url("./images/bl-active.png") left center no-repeat;
    }
.my_button_hover .right {
    float: left;
    width: 10px;
    height: 19px;
    background: url("./images/br-active.png") left center no-repeat;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: You need not to use all the css properties again and again, just use the property you want to change.

Comment: why do you have a separate class for hover? Why not use the `:hover` selector?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

like this

```
.my_button .left,.my_button .right {
        float: left;
        width: 10px;
        height: 19px;
        background: url("./images/bl.png") left center no-repeat;
    }

    .my_button .right {
        background: url("./images/br.png") left center no-repeat;
    }
```

and for hover

```
.my_button:hover .left,.my_button:hover .right {
        float: left;
        width: 10px;
        height: 19px;
        background: url("./images/bl-active.png") left center no-repeat;
    }
.my_button:hover .right {

    background: url("./images/br-active.png") left center no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for ur reply. where is mouse hover css styles?

Comment: i added them now please it

Comment: for hover we write :hover not _hover

Answer (score 0):

Give the common properties a common class, and apply that class on the html element. As such:

```
.commons {
    float: left;
    width: 10px;
    height:19px;
}

.my_button .left {
        background: url("./images/bl.png") left center no-repeat;
    }

.my_button .right {
    background: url("./images/br.png") left center no-repeat;
}

.my_button_hover .left {
        background: url("./images/bl-active.png") left center no-repeat;
    }

.my_button_hover .right {
    background: url("./images/br-active.png") left center no-repeat;
}
```

And in the HTML markup:

```
<a href="#" class="commons my_button left">...</a>
<a href="#" class="commons my_button_hover right">...</a>
```

One could also optmize further by applying the `background-position, background-repeat` options as well.

**EDIT:** You should really look up the `:hover` selector.

Comment: you will be shocked to know that he is trying implement hover  by _hover...lol

Answer (score 0):

Not sure of your site structure, but might this work?

```
.my_button {
        width: 10px;
        height: 19px;
    }
.left {
        float: left;
        background: url("./images/bl.png") left center no-repeat;
    }
.left:hover {
        background: url("./images/bl.png") left center no-repeat;
    }

.right {
float: right;
background: url("./images/br.png") left center no-repeat;
    }
.right:hover {
        background: url("./images/br.png") left center no-repeat;
    }
```